# Mongodb will not create document within if/else statement

Tags: mongodb

New to MongoDB. I'm trying to add a new document to an existing collection only if a document with the same name does not already exist within that collection. I'm using an if/else statement first to check whether there is a document with the same name as the new entry, and if not, an else statement that will create the new entry. Whatever I try, the new document is not getting added, and instead it returns an empty array. I'd be grateful for any help.

I've tried switching the if/else statements; checking for null and undefined values upon return of if statement

```
app.post('/cocktails/new', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
// add to DB then show item
    let name = req.body.name;
    let style = req.body.style;
    let spirit = req.body.spirit;
    let image = req.body.image;
    let description = req.body.description;
    let newCocktail = {name: name, style: style, base: spirit, image: 
    image, description: description}
    Cocktail.find({name}, function (err, existCocktail) {
        if(existCocktail){
            console.log(existCocktail)
}
 else {Cocktail.create(newCocktail, (err, cocktail) => {
console.log(cocktail)
if (err) {console.log(err)}
else {
res.redirect('/cocktails/' + cocktail._id)}
})

        }
    })
})
```

In the event document is not found with the if function, else statements will execute, leading to new document being created with the newCocktail object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use findOne instead of find.

find returns an empty array when no docs found.

The following expression returns true, so your existCocktail condition becomes true, causing your new data not added.

```
[] ? true : false
```

Also I refactor your code a bit, you can use destructuring your req.body.

```
app.post("/cocktails/new", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  // add to DB then show item

  const { name, style, spirit, image, description } = red.body;

  let newCocktail = {
    name,
    style,
    base: spirit,
    image,
    description
  };
  Cocktail.findOne({ name }, function(err, existCocktail) {
    if (existCocktail) {
      console.log(existCocktail);
      res.status(400).json({ error: "Name already exists" });
    } else {
      Cocktail.create(newCocktail, (err, cocktail) => {
        console.log(cocktail);
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went bad" });
        } else {
          res.redirect("/cocktails/" + cocktail._id);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!

Any idea why FindOne works but not Find?

Comment: @monkeytrick good to hear it, can you please accept as answer?

Comment: @monkeytrick Find always return smth. if there is nothing found it returns an empty list. So the check "existCocktail" is always true.

Comment: @S.Kuiter  thank you, I will add this to the answer.

Comment: @monkeytrick I explained the problem with find by editing the answer.